# Creating dictionary and its key- value from line of log-file

Tags: python, dictionary, python-re

I'm trying to do following, if I have the following ERROR line in log file:

```
Aug  9 12:44:39 hostnameABC gnome-terminal-[12581]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6765:28: Missing opening bracket in color definition
```

i need to end up with a dictionary (python), that looks like this:

```
gnome-terminal-[1258] = {ERROR: 1}
```

And if there was already such an dictionary in scope, then ERROR += 1 .
Finally print the dictionary name and Key Value.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: You want to count occurence of ``gnome-terminal-[12581]`` in log file ?

Comment: What makes an error an error?

Comment: Please elaborate on "scope"

Comment: THe error line is signified by presence of "error" in it. Thats when it is error. There could be "info" too , in it.

Comment: THe error line is signified by presence of "error" in it. Thats when it is error. There could be "info" too , in it . Also scope means, if there is another instance of error line forgnome-terminal-[12581] , then we need to check if it is already initialized as dictionary and add 1 to the error key. Or achieve this in any other way.

Comment: Finally, i need to print csv file for all different kind of errors, like: gnome-terminal-[12581] , ERROR, 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

# As I don't have access to the original file, you can
# uncomment the code below to get the lines from the file

#with open('filename.txt') as file:
#     lines = file.readlines()


# Now, assuming  these are the lines from the log file
lines = [
'Aug 9 12:44:39 hostnameABC gnome-terminal-[12581]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6765:28: Missing opening bracket in color definition',
'Aug 9 12:44:39 hostnameABC gnome-terminal-[12581]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6765:28: Missing opening bracket in color definition',
'Aug 9 12:44:39 hostnameABC gnome-terminal-[1581]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6765:28: Missing opening bracket in color definition'
]

er_regex = re.compile(r'gnome-terminal-\[\d+\]')

def er_count():
   count = {}
   er_ins = er_regex.findall(' '.join(lines))
   for er in er_ins:
       count.setdefault(er, 0)
       count[er] += 1
   return(count)

print(er_count())
```

You get a dictionary with a count for each error :)

Comment: thanks for the code contribution. Are you able to change the name, count dictionary to  gnome-terminal-[12581]  ? It is requirement to have the dictionary name by its error type in this case "gnome-terminal-[12581] " . Also remember , if it occurs next time in log file, we need to check if the dictionary already exisit and then add 1 to error count.

Comment: In general, dynamically assigning variable names is [almost never a good idea](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). The best approach would be to have a single dictionary variable, and in it, have keys with the names of errors, with an appropriate value for each one.

As for checking if the dictionary already exists, I'm not sure I understand what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hyphens and square brackets in your variable name. You can get around this by using a higher level dictionary, so that your names with hyphens and square brackets are keys in that dictionary instead. Your solution could look something like this:

```
import re

log = '''Aug  9 12:44:39 hostnameABC gnome-terminal-[12581]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6765:28: Missing opening bracket in color definition
Aug  9 12:44:39 hostnameABC gnome-terminal-[12581]: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:6765:28: Missing opening bracket in color definition
Aug  9 12:44:39 hostnameABC gnome-terminal-[12581]: Info only'''

data = {}

matches = re.findall(r'(gnome-terminal-\[\d+\])(?=.*error)', log)
for match in matches:
  data[match] = data.setdefault(match, {'ERROR': 0})
  data[match]['ERROR'] += 1

print(data)
# {'gnome-terminal-[12581]': {'ERROR': 2}}
```

If you avoid invalid characters in the names, you can use the same approach as above, and just leave out the top level dictionary.

Comment: dictionary name needs to come from log line only, in this case gnome-terminal-[12581]

Comment: Your variable name cannot contain hyphens.

You could do something like this: `error_dicts['gnome-terminal-'] = {}`

Should the dictionary be e.g. 'gnome-terminal-' and the key '12581'? Or do you mean the dict must actually be 'gnome-terminal-[12581]'...?

Comment: ok for simplicity, lets say gnome_terminal instead of gnome-terminal-[12581] in the log file :)  , provided underscore is allowed in var name

Comment: I've updated my answer to get close to what you need, avoiding the hyphens in the dict names by having a top-level dict `data`.

Comment: The square brackets are also an issue, because that is reserved for access into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

THank you folks, specially pitamer and rikus for all your help. I was able to use your input code and idea and make the solution for myself.

```
    error_pattern = r'ticky: ERROR ([\w\s\']*) \((.+)\)'
    info_pattern = r'ticky: INFO.* \((.+)\)'
    user_stat = {}
    
    with open('syslog.log','r') as logs:
      for line in logs.readlines():
        if re.search(error_pattern,line):
          results = re.search(error_pattern, line)
          user_stat.setdefault(results.group(2),[0,0])[1]+=1
        if re.search(info_pattern,line):
          results = re.search(info_pattern, line)
          user_stat.setdefault(results.group(1),[0,0])[0]+=1
    
    user_sorted = sorted(user_stat.items())
    
with open('user_statistics.csv','w') as output:
  csvfiler = csv.writer(output)
  csvfiler.writerow(['Username','INFO','ERROR'])
  for item in user_sorted:
      onerow = [item[0],item[1][0],item[1][1]]
      csvfiler.writerow(onerow)
```